# Microsoft JScript compilation error

Tags: windows-7, java, scheduled-tasks

For the past month until now, I'm getting the follow dialog from time to time. Probably few times a week. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 with all latest updates, and Java 6U29 (1.6.0_29-b11)

[image: Microsoft JScript compilation error][image]

After noticing the icon on the taskbar and some trial and error, I found out that it's from jusched.exe, javaws.exe and javaw.exe. It will disappear if I end task javaw.exe.

[image: Screenshot from Process Explorer]

The commandline property is

- javaws.exe:

  ```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaws.exe"
     -silent -import -reverse -javafxau -system
     -J-Dkernel.download.dialog=false ""http://dl.javafx.com/javafx-cache.jnlp""
  ```
- javaw.exe:

  ```
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe" 
    "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\javaws.jar;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\deploy.jar;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\plugin.jar"
     -classpath "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\deploy.jar" 
    "-Djava.security.policy=file:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\security\\javaws.policy"
     -DtrustProxy=true
     -Xverify:remote
    "-Djnlpx.home=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin"
     -Dsun.awt.warmup=true
     -Djnlpx.origFilenameArg=http://dl.javafx.com/javafx-cache.jnlp 
     -Djnlpx.remove=false
     -Djava.awt.headless=true
     -Dkernel.download.dialog=false
    "-Djnlpx.jvm=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe" 
     -Djnlpx.vmargs=-Dkernel.download.dialog=false com.sun.javaws.Main
     -silent -import -reverse -javafxau -system http://dl.javafx.com/javafx-cache.jnlp
  ```

I'm wondering what is the scheduler calling, and is this a bug or just some incompatibility on my machine. I didn't find much related info from googling.

Comment: I have had this same problem on three of my machines.  One Win7 x64 Home Premium, one Win7 x64 Ultimate, and one... XP Home x32...

Comment: @faulty did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @RichK, Nope. The machine has since been formatted. But it doesn't reoccur with 7u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue and found the answer below to be the solution for me

> Solution:
> •In Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings
> •Clear the checkbox in ”Automatically detect settings”
>
> Antonio Álvarez

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/microsoft-jscript-compilation-error-syntax-error/e0c048cb-74ca-4d8c-b17f-36b5ca7245de

Cheers!
Jeremy

Comment: Sorry, I can't verify the problem now as I've formatted all my machines and use JRE 7 since. Anyway, the source was a good find. I'll mark your's as answer

Answer (score 5):

This error message means that there is a syntax error in your [Proxy auto-config file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) (PAC file). Probably jusched.exe (the Java Updater) uses JScript to interpret the PAC file, because it needs to detect the correct proxy server.